# My java programe doesn't loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

So this is my first loop and when i execute it ,it says,
"Enter the price of item 1"
,and when i give it an input, it displays the output without looping even once

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Loop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        int value;
        int sum=0;
        int number=1;
        while (number > 6);

        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the price of item"+number);
            value = input.nextInt( );
            sum=sum+value;
            number=number+1;
        }

double vat=value*0.15;
double total=value+vat;
System.out.println("The Total cost is $"+value+" \n The Value added tax is $"+vat+"\n The total cost including Value Added Tax is $"+total);
      }
  }
```

can somebody please help me?

Comment: is the condition "1>6" true?

Comment: Two problems: `while (number > 6)` for `number = 1` is false so loop finishes instantly, but even if it didn't finish you have `;` right after it so its body is empty statement, not the code block you want.

Answer (score 3):

a couple of problems here

```
 int number=1;
 while (number > 6);
```

number is less than six so it would never enter

and

remove the semicolon after the while

Answer (score 2):

You define

```
    int number=1;
```

And you test

```
   while (number > 6);
    {   
    <some code>
    }
```

The condition is never met since number is 1.

There's also another problem: the semicolon after the while will lead to an infinite loop if you correct just the condition

Fixed code:

```
   while (number < 6)  // <- no semicolon & correct comparison
    {   
        System.out.println("Enter the price of item"+number);
        value = input.nextInt( );
        sum=sum+value;
        number=number+1;
    }
```

Comment: @apomene I like your style: downvote but cancel downvote when appropriate :) some people only do the first part.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your number is not `> 6` in the first place. So it would never satisfy the entering condition of the loop because clearly 1 is not greater than 6. Instead you want to loop while it is `< 6`. You also need to remove the `;` after your while.

So try to replace with that:

```
int number=1;
while (number < 6)
{   
    System.out.println("Enter the price of item"+number);
    value = input.nextInt( );
    sum=sum+value;
    number=number+1;
 }
```

Comment: this will result in an infinite loop

Comment: @apomene my bad, did not write what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

You have bad while condition, change `while (number > 6);` to `while (number < 6)`, remmeber to remove the ; after the while

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a semicolon after the *while* statement.

```
    while (number > 6);
```

Though it is not syntactically wrong but when you want to loop, the semicolon must be omitted.

Secondly, **number** is initialized to **1** and while loop checks whether **1 > 6**, which is false.